# How to deserialize array collection in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, serialization, amf

I am stuck with an issue: 
In which I am serializing an array collection to a file, the array collection has two type of items an Image and a class object.
It serialize successfully, but when I de-serialize it, It simply returns array collection of objects   and I found my self unable to convert these objects into Images and the class object(this class is defined by myself and having three members, two images and a shape).

I am adding the code which I used:

```
[Bindable] var objcnvs:ClassCanvas;
        protected function btnSave_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //for saving  data serializaion

            var arrAllSave:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            for(var i:int = 0;i<arrAll.length; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    var tempCon:ConnectImage = arrAll[i];
                    arrAllSave.addItem({item:arrAll[i], type:"ConnectImage" });                             
                }
                catch(er:Error)
                {
                    var tempImage:Image = arrAll[i];
                    var objImage:ClassImage = new ClassImage(arrAll[i]);
                    arrAllSave.addItem({item:objImage, type:"Image" });                 
                }
            }

            // First, generate your ByteArray from the VO.
            var byteArray : ByteArray = new ByteArray();

            byteArray.writeObject( arrAll );

            // Resolve your file location.
            //var file : File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath( "testFile.ri" );

            var mapName:String = txtMapTitle.text;

            var file : File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath( 'Saved Maps/'+mapName+'.imm' );
            if(file.exists == true)
            {
                lblWarn.text = "Map already Exists. Please enter Defferent Map Title";  
            }
            else if(mapName == "")
            {
                lblWarn.text = "Please enter a title for Map.";
            }
            else
            {                       
                var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
                // Save the file to the given location.
                fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
                fileStream.writeBytes( byteArray );
                fileStream.close();

                lblWarn.text = "Map Saved successfully";
            }           

        }

        protected function btnLoadMap_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {           

            // Execute the file load.
            var loadFileName:String = "t1"; 
            var request : URLRequest = new URLRequest ( "app-storage:/"+"Saved Maps/"+loadFileName+".imm" );
            var receptor : URLLoader = new URLLoader( request );

            // Make sure our content is interpreted as a ByteArray.
            receptor.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
            receptor.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, fileLoadedHandler );


        }
        private function fileLoadedHandler ( event : Event ) : void
        {
            // Retrieve the event target, cast as the URLLoader we just created
            var loader : URLLoader = event.target as URLLoader;

            // Retrieve the loaded data. We know it's a ByteArray, so let's cast it as well.
            var data : ByteArray = loader.data as ByteArray;

            // Use the ByteArray.readObject method to reconstruct the object.
            var obj : Object = data.readObject();

            // Cast the object and assign it to our data container.

            var loadArrAll:ArrayCollection = obj as ArrayCollection;

        }
```

The last line

```
var loadArrAll:ArrayCollection = obj as ArrayCollection;
```

this is the issue. I get the array collection but it has only a list of objects no images and no my class objects (although these are there but  I found no way to convert this array collection in previous form when I serialized it.)

Comment: I found some '[Remote class alias=(...)]'. some thing like this Can anybody tell me how I can use it with my issue.

Comment: Not everything is automatically serializable for those classes that doesn't you have to write code yourself (you will register the alias with the snippet you've added in comment.

Comment: Hey  Lukasz 'Severiaan' Grela, Can you give some code examples for this I think this my be a solution.

Comment: Why dont you serialized/deserialised on server side?

Answer (score 0):

class that needs to be serialized/deserialised needs to implement [flash.utils.IExternalizable](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/IExternalizable.html).

```
    public function readExternal(input:IDataInput):void - here you restore object
    public function writeExternal(output:IDataOutput):void - here you saving object
```

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Zain, you have to declare your classes like that:

```
package com
{
    [RemoteClass]
    public class myClass
    {
        public function myClass()
        {
        }
    }
}
```